# SSRS chart x-axis, group by one value but label with another

Tags: graph, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

For example, this might be the result in my data set:

```
QuarterValue        QuarterLabel       InterestingNumber
  0                   Q1 - FY12/13        57
  1                   Q2 - FY12/13        83
  2                   Q3 - FY12/13        64
  3                   Q4 - FY12/13        75
  4                   Q1 - FY13/14        35
  5                   Q2 - FY13/14        29
  6                   Q3 - FY13/14        48
  7                   Q4 - FY13/14        55
```

I want to have a bar graph on my report, where the x-axis is Quarter and the y-axis is the so-called InterestingNumber.  I want the x-axis to be grouped and sorted by QuarterValue, but labeled by QuarterLabel.

So far, I have tried changing the "Label" expression in the graph's "Category Group Properties", and it had no effect.  Meanwhile, I have looked around in the "Horizontal Axis Properties" and found nothing helpful.  Notice that I can't just group by x-axis by QuarterLabel, because then all the Q1's will be together, etc. out of proper date order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me with your data with the steps you describe:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So your methodology is correct. I would recommend creating a new chart from scratch with the fewest steps possible to see if you can get it going, then add new formatting/functionality, checking it doesn't break the labels.

The other option is your sample data is not reflecting your actual data accurately; maybe you can create a dummy DataSet with the values you mentioned and see if you can create a chart similar to the one above as a proof of concept.

Comment: "...recommend creating a new chart from scratch with the fewest steps possible..." allowed me discover that the issue lay in changing the axis properties between Category and Scalar.  I had assumed that since my QuarterValues were scalars this was required, but I guess not.